# I am using jasmine and angular mock to check if a method is been called but is not working

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a service object that makes a call to the backend to fetch a project by id, it works fine but when I mock the get method during testing the method is not being called, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am using a `Jasmine2` and do not mock the httpbackend, I use the `returnValue` to set the response but somehow the returnValue is not waorking

This is the service

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('moduleName')
        .factory('Project', Project);

    Project.$inject = ['$resource'];

    function Project ($resource) {
        var resourceUrl =  'api/projects/:id';

        return $resource(resourceUrl, {}, {
            'query': { method: 'GET', isArray: true},
            'get': {
                method: 'GET',
                transformResponse: function (data) {
                    if (data) {
                        data = angular.fromJson(data);
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            },
            'update': { method:'PUT' }
        });
    }
})();
```

The controller looks like this

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('moduleName')
        .controller('ProjectController', ProjectController);

    ProjectController.$inject = ['Project'];

    function ProjectControllerr(Project) {
        var vm = this;
      vm.project = Project.get(1);
    }
})();
```

This is the test

```
'use strict';

describe('Project Controller Tests', function () {

    beforeEach(module('moduleName'));

    describe('Project Controller', function () {
        var $scope, $state, ProjectMock, stateMock, stateParamsMock;

        beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope) {

            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            ProjectMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('Project', ['get']);
            ProjectMock.get.and.returnValue({id:1,name:'data'});

            stateParamsMock = {projectId: 1};

        }));

        describe('When a project is not empty', function () {

            beforeEach(inject(function ($controller,Project) {

                $controller('ProjectsController as vm',
                    {
                        $scope: $scope,
                        Project: ProjectMock,
                        $state: stateMock
                    });
            }));

            it('Should fetch current project by id', function () {

                expect(ProjectMock.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect($scope.vm.project.id).toBe(1);
            });

        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling `ProjectMock.get();` That's why you are not getting response.So,your expectation `toHaveBeenCalled` is false if you checked it.

Do the following changes.

```
it('Should fetch current project by id', function () {
  ProjectMock.get();
  expect(ProjectMock.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
   expect($scope.vm.project.id).toBe(1);
});
```